# Perform animation when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have progress bar with bootstrap , this is html :

```js
  $(".progress-bar").each(function () { // .each(function (i, item) work too!
                var progressBar = $(this); // $(this) would work too
                progressBar.animate({
                    width: progressBar.data('width') + '%'
                }, 1500);
            });
```

```html
<body>
  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class='jumbotron' style='height:1400px' width='auto'>
<h1>please scroll down</h1>

</div>


    <div class="alert alert-success">
      <div class="skill-name">ON PROGRESS 357/487</div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" data-width="70">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="alert alert-danger">
      <div class="skill-name">FAILED 30/487</div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" data-width="30">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </body>
```

The animation is running when I load the HTML, so to animate progress-bar is not working.
How to animate when I scroll down to view progress-bar ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/lRLMiaE7Gy

**Jquery** :

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".progress-bar:not(.animated)").each(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                var progressBar = $(this); // $(this) would work too
                progressBar.animate({
                    width: progressBar.data('width') + '%'
                }, 1500);
                progressBar.addClass('animated');
      }
    });
  }); 
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".progress-bar:not(.animated)").each(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                var progressBar = $(this); // $(this) would work too
                progressBar.animate({
                    width: progressBar.data('width') + '%'
                }, 1500);
                progressBar.addClass('animated');
      }
    });
  }); 
});
```

```html
<body>
  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class='jumbotron' style='height:1400px' width='auto'>
<h1>please scroll down</h1>

</div>


    <div class="alert alert-success">
      <div class="skill-name">ON PROGRESS 357/487</div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" data-width="70">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="alert alert-danger">
      <div class="skill-name">FAILED 30/487</div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" data-width="30">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: This works, however the amount of work done for each scroll may be a performance hit.

Comment: I'm totally agree with you,until all element are visible